# Is there a way to see how Kurento elements are connected?

Tags: kurento, kurento-media-server

I'm debugging my application using Kurento and need to check if MediaElements in a MediaPipeline are connected as I expected. Is there any way to tell how elements are connected to each other on the server side?

Thanks,

DK